# How to add a break/pause of few seconds to Google assistant response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-cx, ssml

While sending a response to the user how do I add a pause/break of few seconds?
Here is an example:

```
Response text: "The answer to the question is  < Pause-For-2-Seconds > answer"
```

I tried the `<break = "2s" />` and that do not work for me.

Comment: Please add what you really tried.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use SSML on your answer, to do that just wrap what your response is with `<speak>` tag then add another tag `<break time="2s"/>`, like this:

```
<speak>The answer to the question is <break time="2s"/> answer</speak>
```

For a more complete information on SSML check [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml).

Answer (score 0):

For voice agents its often important to use [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/) in their responses to make their output sound more natural.

For Dialogflow-CX that works when the fullfillment response comes from a webhook request.
That works like following: Your Dialogflow agent sends a WebhookRequest to your servers. The called route responds with an WebhookResponse object containing a FullfillmentResponse with an according ResponseMessage that got outputAudioText property set with proper ssml key set up.
Your agent will use that response and e.g. make a pause after certain word like in my example following.

To clearify that a bit I will show you an example WebhookResponse object and how it could look:

```
const returnObject: WebhookResponse = {
        
        fulfillmentResponse: {
            messages: [
                {
                    responseType: ResponseType.RESPONSE_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED,
                    channel: 'default',
                    outputAudioText: {
                        allowPlaybackInterruption: false,
                        ssml: `<speak>Okay, vielen Dank! Wir übermitteln Ihren Namen, Rufnummer 
                        und Ihre gewünschte Rückrufzeit an unser Vertriebsteam und versuchen Sie 
                        am $session.params.date um $session.params.time Uhr zu erreichen <break time="1s"/>Auf wiedersehen</speak>`,
                    },
                },
            ],
            mergeBehavior: MergeBehavior.REPLACE,
        },

        sessionInfo: {
            session: body.sessionInfo.session,
            parameters: {
                time: '12:30',
                date: '11.1.2024',
            },
        },
    }
```

Here you can see the bespoke fullfillment response and the use of SMLL to further instruct the TTS system on how to act.
Furthermore $session parameters are overwritten via the sessionInfo property. This overwritten paramters are also used in the agent response created via our SMLL expression.